# Creating an isolate bed environment for sleeping (to reduce mechanical vibration from floor)

Tags: vibration, sound-isolation

Having a serious issue with mechanical vibration in my home (I call it "mechanical" because its nature is not from sound, but rather from some sort of a device - for clear image whats happening, please refer [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40462/reducing-vibration-coming-from-the-floor-while-at-sleep) - tried almost all ways as suggested there, with no obvious effect). And I need to sleep ASAP...

In other words - I need to create a very isolate bed environment. Rebuilding floor is not an option. Need something what I can add up to the current state of the apartment. Probably most radical way (construction wise) could possible be to create a second floor (for bed area only), attaching it to the walls (by making holes in walls).

But the actual idea I am looking for - is hanging bed. The question here - would it work? Could someone do some calculations whatsoever, to get a better picture of what result that could bring? F.ex. I imagine, for some level of vibration, some vibration force could endup making bed to swing (what sounds as a less damaging effect to me, while at sleep). Also, maybe there is a chance for vibration to exhaust while traveling via that construction?

Could someone please give some advice?

[image]

EDIT:

---

Now thought of maybe a better design. See image below. Idea - to place next to walls (to the right and to the left of the bed) some solid material (like very solid wood, metal etc.) which then is jointed via the ceiling. And attaching ropes to hang a bed. In this design, I really think vibration would not travel to the bed.

Anyone could please comment this? You help is needed so much, people...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the easier things first, like inserting rubber floor pads under the bed's legs?

Comment: On what bed the sailor sleeps during sailing? Get the same. :)

Comment: Thats pretty much what my award winning design points to. The challenge - make it strong, cheap and easily mountable. Thinking graded wood should hold the weight - one frame from front of the bed, other for back. Totally about 3 graded wood poles needed (if 3m.length), then chains / ropes and mounting hooks. All this under 100eur possible. But will it work...? My logic says yes. Do you people agree? :)

Comment: @r13 A hammock, yes! Cheaper to try than building a whole bed, that's for sure.  I am skeptical whether it would work. Also this looks a lot like a duplicate question, so you should edit to be really clear in what way it is different from the previous post

Comment: Hammock considering useful only to take a nap.

Comment: cheaper way to test the concept though. In the case of a pendulum, the resonant frequency will be determined by the length, so you can test the principle without building a bunch of stuff

Comment: @Pete W - what if I mount hanging bed to the ceiling? Do you think it would work in that case?

Comment: I'm telling you, I have serious doubts. But a hammock can test it, and you will still have something that is useful even if it doesn't work.

Comment: @PeteW - but what makes you think mounted on ceiling wouldnt work? There is no contact with vibrating floor... How it is even possible to it not to work...?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe your ceiling is stiffer than your floor? Wasn't it your upstairs neighbor? And if you put up on a frame, that will still be on the floor

Comment: @PeteW I am on top floor. And in general - no frustration comes from anywhere else than from the bellow floors

Comment: I still think what is happening is the whole building is moving a little bit, so that includes both floor and ceiling. It is probably moving side to side, because buildings tend to be very stiff in the vertical direction. So it would depend on whether the hammock is a less sensitive "antenna" to the building's resonant frequency, compared to your bed. Maybe it is, maybe not. Depends on the length of the pendulum. If you want to test it, tie a weight to a rope, and attach your cel phone to the weight also, and use an accelerometer app to measure the vibrations.

Comment: @PeteW I want to believe in my design because - 1. Vibration would not be direct - it would need to travel up the pole, then to the right on horizontal pole and finaly down the ropes via the joint.  And at the end, some of that force whould endup swinging bed a little instead of shaking it. Would you agree?

Comment: I am skeptical like I said, but of course I don't know. Do some experiment to find out, I gave some test suggestions that will waste less money and material in case it doesn't work. Have to go work now, good luck!

Comment: @PeteW Thanks, will try to test. Great advice!

Comment: Driving 4 eye screws into the rafters is the best option in my opinion. I'd dangle the bed from sturdy ropes instead of chains as that might have a small damping effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing vibration coming from the floor while at sleep](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40462/reducing-vibration-coming-from-the-floor-while-at-sleep)

Comment: @Bregalad - probably, not sure. Vibration is a kinda a magical process. And it got me sucked in. However, none of the tests I was making, gave undoubtfull results, so exploration is still in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Springs and dampers are the classic method to reduce vibration, but don't expect the solution to be easy.  Vibrations is a 4000 level ME course.

If the problem is just the floor, then hanging the bed is probably the easiest option.  I would recommend 4 ropes or chains anchored into the ceiling joists above the bed.